# Migrating from ASP.NET Web Site to Web Application. Where to put App_Code files

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, migration

I am migrating my web site to web application and not sure where to put app_code files? I have moved the whole app_code folder to web application but while compiling web app I get error that classes are not found.

Answer (score 1):

I think once an Web Application, the App_Code folder is relatively useless...as in, it doesn't have its special meaning that it has within a WebSite project. So there's nothing stopping you still having a folder called App_Code and putting your classes (and whatever other files) in there.

It may make more sense to put the files within folders and namespace the classes with relevance logical groupings (helper classes, business rules, data access, whatever) or perhaps move the classes into a separate Windows Class Library project (DLL) which your web application references...

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I must mark files inside app_code as compile and everything will work.